# Model turning 2d when it's parented

Tags: unity, transformation, first-person-shooter, importing

I'm importing arms from blender for my first person controller but when I make the player the Arms' parent it turns 2d. I have no idea why this is happening so if anyone could help it would be very appreciated.

[image: Unparented Arms]

[image: Parented Arms]

[image: Player Scale Factors]

I'm very confused lol

Comment: Show us the scale factors on your player object.

Comment: There, thanks for the comment I guess it's because the x is 0 didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

When creating my empty game object the scale along the x axis was 0. This meant that when I made the player (An empty game object) the parent, the arms inherited the 0 scale on the x factor. To fix this, change the scale on the x axis to 1 on the player gameobject :).

Comment: "When creating an empty game object the scale along the x axis is 0" This is not true in general.  Normally a new empty GameObject will be created with scale (1, 1, 1)

Comment: Any idea why mine was made this way then?

Comment: @JeffBrin The best advice I could give is, when creating/moving a `GameObject`, and it doesn't look right, it's often a good idea to go on the Hierarchy and do Right Click on `Transform` and `Reset`. Then give it the position that you want. There have been many times that Unity tried to calculate positions and scales on objects I move around, and it failed.